# coldfusion - how to loop the value that was passed from getElementById in the same page?

Tags: coldfusion

I want to loop the selected number from the list (cfselect).   I tried getElementById but only able to display it on the same page.  I cannot pass this number to the loop.  Can someone help me? Thank you.

```
function item()

        var a = document.formName.numList.selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById('i').value = document. family.tBro.options[a].value;

        var n=document. family.tBro.options[a].value;


<!----OTHER INPUT TEXT BOXES --->

<cfform name="family" action="complete.cfm" method="post">

     How many brothers do you have?
     <cfselect name="tBro" onChange="item();" required="yes">
        <option value="1"> 1</option>
        <option value="2"> 2</option> 
        <option value="3"> 3</option>  
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </cfselect>                                                    

   <!---DISPLAY THE SELECTED CHOICE from getElementById--->
   Total number of brothers: <cfinput type="text" name="i" id="i">


   <!---LOOP x amount of time  from selected choice above. 
       For example, if 2 is selected, the below info will display two times
   --->

   <cfinput type="text" name="firstname"  required="yes">
   <cfinput type="text" name="lastname"  required="yes">
   <cfinput type="text" name="Age"  required="yes">
   <cfinput type="text" name="Ocupation"  required="yes">

   <!--- END LOOP--->
```

Comment: You could probably benefit from reading this: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html

Comment: @Ulala Zing - Tip: To post cfml/html code, just use the code ie `{}` button in the toolbar. That will preserve the `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 5):

Tip: state what you're trying to accomplish, rather than the implementation. I had to reread it a few times to understand your need, in which case what your implementation isn't really a good fit.

You're trying to pass JavaScript to CFM code: that's not the way it works. ColdFusion is rendered on the server; JavaScript is rendered on the client. At the moment when item() is called, ColdFusion has finished all of its rendering; you can't effect a CF loop with the result of item().

Without a really complex AJAX solution, you have 2 choices:

1. refresh the browser when init() is called where you pass dropdown value in the url (not good, as you'd lose state of other form fields)
2. use something else like jQuery to render your dynamic list of text fields. This is probably the best approach, and a common one. The downside of this is you'll need to implement things like "required" in jQuery, which isn't a big deal, and a common use case.